# Count occurrences of an element in a list

Tags: haskell

I've been learning Haskell from LYAH for quite some time, and as a first practice for Chapter 7: Modules, I decided to make a simple `numTimesFound` function: it returns the number of times an element is found in a list.

Here's my working code:

```
numTimesFound :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> Integer
numTimesFound _ [] = 0
numTimesFound x list
  | x `notElem` list = 0
  | otherwise =
      let
        appearencesTable = map (\full@(first:_) -> (first, length full + 1)) . group . sort $ list
        appearencesOfX = snd $ head $ filter (\(elem, _) -> elem == x) appearencesTable
      in
        toInteger appearencesOfX
```

Personally, I think I take the cake for using Haskell features, but I also think that the intent of this code is hard to understand. One of my major gripes with it is that it's hard to tell what the `appearencesTable` actually is from the code - it's a list of tuples that gives you the number of times each element was found. For example, for the list `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]` the `appearencesTable` is `[(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 4), (4, 2), (5, 1)]`. If you know that it's pretty easy to get what the rest of the code is trying to do, but it still does require quite a bit of study for such a trivial function.

I would greatly appreciate any help in improving the readability of this code.

Comment: For those who don't know, "LYAH" is [Learn You A Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your type a is required to be an Ord you can access Eq functions. This makes counting occurrences a bit simpler, because you can just filter and count the matching elements:

```
numTimesFound :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> Integer
numTimesFound _ [] = 0
numTimesFound x list = sum $ map (\a -> 1) $ filter (== x) list
```

Of course we don't need to stop there. We can use function composition and `length` to  write the last line as:

```
numTimesFound x xs = (length . filter (== x)) xs
```

In addition to that [200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success) raises an interesting point in the comments:

> Actually, there is no reason to require `Ord a`, when `Eq a` will do

Comment: Man that was simpler than I thought! I guess the style of thinking has to  be pretty different to write readable code in Haskell. Thanks so much!

Comment: Note that you don’t need the explicit case to handle the empty list at all; `count` will happily return `0` if the list is empty.

Comment: Wait, I just realized - the `count` function is the same as `length`, so I can just write my original function as `numTimesFound x = length . filter (==x)`! I am so dumb!

Comment: Actually, there is no reason to require `Ord a`, when `Eq a` will do.

Comment: @200_success: Yes, that is true. The only reason I was using `Ord` originally was because I used `sort`.